# Is it possible to create a parallax effect on a website, that is styled using flexbox? If so, how would that be done?

Tags: html, css, parallax

Like the question states, I have been having trouble confirming whether the use of a parallax type of effect is possible while using flexbox. Almost all examples I run across are using absolute and relative positions.

Is parallax possible while using flexbox? If so, how?

Comment: It depends on what type of parallax you want. For more information watch this series on parallax. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=STwoa-9jxi0&list=PLqGj3iMvMa4IyCbhul-PdeiDqmh4ooJzk

Comment: It doesn't really matter, which specific type, I just want to know if its possible and if I can see a basic example, using flexbox.